# Polymer ready vs connectedCallback

Tags: polymer-2.x

I'm wondering what is is the importance of `ready()` method in polymer and what is the meaning of on-time initialization for such method and what is the differences between `read()` and `connectedCallback()` ???

Comment: do you need more details? or are the answers sufficient enough?

Comment: sufficient enough

Comment: if so pls accept an answer thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should help.

> connectedCallback can be called more than once

...

> Generally all setup work in connectedCallback should be balanced with associated teardown work in disconnectedCallback; if not it usually means connectedCallback is the wrong place to do it

...

> At this point it's hard to contrive general a use case where ready is the only/best place to do work, although they do come up from time to time in very specific cases.

...

> ready is called only once, so work done here based on a property value may become invalidated if the property value is changed at a later point by the user

See https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/4108#issuecomment-258983943

Answer (score 0):

They both have the same "goal". To provide a way of doing something after the element has been placed in the dom.

`ready` is polymer specific while `connectedCallback` is in the spec.

So if you have a vanilla webcomponent only connectedCallback is available. For Polymer Elements you may still use ready (especially if you convert an element  from Polymer 1)

There are however some timing differences discribed here:
https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#custom-elements-apis

> The ready callback, for one-time initialization, signals the creation
>   of the element's shadow DOM. In the case of class-based elements, you
>   need to call super.ready() before accessing the shadow tree.
>
> The major difference between 1.x and 2.0 has to do with the timing of
>   initial light DOM distribution. In the v1 shady DOM polyfill, initial
>   distribution of children into  is asynchronous (microtask) to
>   creating the shadowRoot, meaning distribution occurs after observers
>   are run and ready is called. In the Polymer 1.0 shim, initial
>   distribution occurred before ready.